# How do i make it show decimals

Tags: c++, calculator

I have been watching youtube and different guides on internet and thought it would be fun to make a calculator because i have seen many do it, Here is what i have started. It works fine but i want it to be able to show decimals too. All answers are appreciated. (I have a bunch of #Include but ignore those)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cstdio>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

  std::cout << "My first caclulator\nPlease enter your first number: ";
  int x, y;
  std::cin >> x;
  std::cout << "Please enter the other number: ";
  std::cin >> y;
  int w = x*y;
  int c = x + y;
  int v = x - y;
  int q = x / y;
  std::cout << "\nNumbers multiplied: " << w << endl;
  std::cout << "\nNumbers added together: " << c << endl;
  std::cout << "\nNumbers subtracted: " << v << endl;
  std::cout << "\nNumbers divided: " << q << endl;
  _tprintf(_T("Press any key to exit "));
  while (_kbhit() ) _gettch();

    _gettch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read about difference between `int` and `float` or `double` type.

Comment: Your code doesn't [live in the realm](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ad8de13d5963f13) of standard c++.

Answer (score 0):

All your calculations are done with integer mathematics, therefore there are no decimals involved (all values are truncated).  You can alter the code to use `double` but then you will end up with a large number of decimal places, so best to round using `setprecision`, for example:

```
double w = x*y;
double c = x + y;
double v = x - y;
double q = x / y;
std::cout << "\nNumbers multiplied: " << setprecision(2) << w << endl;
std::cout << "\nNumbers divided: " << setprecision(2) << q << endl;
```

Comment: `setprecision` would need `std::` prefix (or a `using` statement) and an additional `#include`. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the decimals, you have to use another data type. 
Try something like `double` or `float`.

Example:

```
 double w = x*y;
 double c = x + y;
 double v = x - y;
 double q = x / y;
```

This should work fine.
If you need more informations about other data types check this out: [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/)